# Role_path on AWX

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I'm launching a job on AWX that use a project that contains a playbook ( ansible roles)  like this:

```
- name: Running script
  script: generate_t0_vars.sh {{ t0_count }} "{{ role_path }}"
  register: output

- include_vars: "{{ role_path }}/vars/main.yml"
```

I'm using this bash script to evaluate role_path:

```
#!/bin/bash
t0_count=$1
role_path=$2
t0_name=()
for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 1 $t0_count); do t0_name+=(T0_GW_$i); done

echo -n "" > "$role_path/vars/main.yml"
echo "vars_t0:" >> "$role_path/vars/main.yml"

for i in $(seq 0 $((${#t0_name[@]} - 1)))
do
        echo "  - t0_name: ${t0_name[$i]}" >> "$role_path/vars/main.yml
done
```

I'm trying to evaluate the value of the role_path variable in order to use it in other roles as a reference point ( as I don't want to hard-code the directory of the project ). The problem is that AWX tower won't be able to identify it. I got this error when launching the job template:

```
"/home/user/.ansible/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1669894315.1132782-31686-208889357499252/generate_t0_vars.sh: 
 /tmp/awx_2484_zvvoz0dl/project/roles/t0_create/vars/main.yml: No such file or directory"
```

I've tried to modify roles_path in ansible.cfg , but, it doesn't work. Also, It tried to set as "remote_tmp". However, it seems that AWX could not find the location of my bash script to run it. Only if I put exactly the directory of my project inside the playbook, AWX job will run it.

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you simply use the role? The vars in `vars/main.yml` will be loaded automatically and you don't have to know a role's path to use it.

Comment: Actually, I did use it. As you can see, I used the bash script to input variables & generate automatically in ```vars/main.yml```. But, AWX won't know exactly the directory if I don't input in playbook. The main point is to use 1 directory for vars folder so I can re-use this code without conflict directory path issue :(

Comment: No you did not "use" the role, your are simply trying to include a file containing vars which happens to sit inside a role. "Using" a role is done either with the `role` keyword at play level or by using `include_role` or `import_role` in a task.

Comment: Just trying to put you on track and shed some light on my above comments if needed: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/dd57be01a977ed609f11300faf2cc7c2